# How to disable wifi show password in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, security, wifi, ubuntu-18.04, disable

Is there any way to disable wifi show password in ubuntu 18.04 or is there any way stop system to store wifi passwords.

Comment: All OSes have this out of box, what you're asking is a feature request. You could however restrict access to network settings by : `sudo chmod 700 $(sudo which nm-connection-editor)`

Comment: If this answers your question, I will add it as answer, please accept for future readers.

Comment: Sure, Accepted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All OSes have this out of box, what you're asking is a feature request. You could however restrict access to network settings by : `sudo chmod 700 $(which nm-connection-editor)`. However, As mentioned by @triplee, changing permissions on system resources is not a ideal/recommended solution.

Comment: There should be no need to `sudo` the `which` command. Changing the permissions on system resources is pretty dubious advice.

Comment: @triplee I see. How do they suggest he can achieve what he wants to ? It simply isn't possible. This is as far as he can go.

Comment: While that's probably true, I think you should add a caveat about this. It's probably fine on your home system but nothing like this should ever be undertaken in a production deployment.

Comment: @triplee Yeah, you're right about caveat. I assumed he'd know consequences.